# Bulk INSERT into SQL Server CE

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, webmatrix, navicat

I am using WebMatrix for a site right now, and its built-in SQL Server Compact database, and it's alright, but it only lets you create one row at a time. It has no bulk insert features (as I expected). But, see I have tens of thousands of rows in a spreadsheet.

I used to use Navicat for SQL Server which let me define a table name, then it would automatically IMPORT the spreadsheet into a table! Tens of thousands of rows, All within about 30seconds. How can I get Navicat for SQL Server to connect to WebMatrix's database for my website so I can do mass-bulk-inserts?

Answer (score 2):

I have a Bulk Insert library, that you may be able to use: http://sqlcebulkcopy.codeplex.com

Comment: Hmmm, looks promising. I'll go check it out! Thanks.